# How to turn an HTML table into a list in Internet Explorer

Tags: html

I have a dynamically generated table in my page, which was generated by a 3rd party source (its an MLS feed) with 10 rows, 5 columns. I can't request much else. I want to display it as ONE column, hence, like a list. I have managed to do this on Firefox, Safari, and Chrome, but when I work with it in IE, the two effects I get are: each TD element  in each row overlaps like a hand of cards in poker while maintaining the TR spacing - OR - it will stack the TDs AND the TRs all into one pile of IE crap. Finally, nothing I do in CSS seems to change my table's width or TD width. o.O. Commencing hair removal tactics.

Page example:
http://www.vdbestates.com/beta/residential.html (view in Firefox and IE for best illustration)

Html:

```
<table id="IDX-showcaseWrapper-residentialListings" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="z-index: -1;">
            <td class="IDX-showcaseDetails" valign="top" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px 0px 8px;"></td>
            <td class="IDX-showcaseDetails" valign="top" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px 0px 8px;"></td>
            <td class="IDX-showcaseDetails" valign="top" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px 0px 8px;"></td>
            <td class="IDX-showcaseDetails" valign="top" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px 0px 8px;"></td>
            <td class="IDX-showcaseDetails" valign="top" style="text-align: center; padding: 0px 0px 8px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="z-index: -1;"></tr>
            ...
        <tr style="height: auto; z-index: -1;"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am using jQuery to dynamically assign new "top" values to the TDs in the other browsers, using a for loop, multiplying the index by the TD height:

```
var tCell;
for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    tCell = $('td.IDX-showcaseDetails').eq(i);
    $(tCell).attr('style', 'top:' + (i * 250) + 'px;');     
}
```

CSS:
(all browsers)

```
table[id^=IDX-showcaseWrapper] {
    position:relative;
    min-height:1200px !important;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    z-index:1;
    display:block;
}
table[id^=IDX-showcaseWrapper] tr {
    position:relative;
}
.IDX-showcaseDetails {
    display:list-item !important;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:480px;
    height:275px;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    border-bottom:1px solid #5c4a57;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    padding:0px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not read your data out of the table, re-write it into a list, then remove the table? Messing around with CSS to emulate this will surely drive you mad. Use JavaScript instead.

Comment: Well sir, you are right! I did basically what you suggested and it worked very well. Thanks again. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite shure i understand you problem but how about writing a new list and not messing with the old one?
Iterate to the old one, fetching the values and print the new html.

Comment: I can turn a table into a list in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome. I feel like I'm one silly IE CSS rendering bug away from getting it right in IE too...

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked very well. I appreciate your input! I would vote you up but I can't yet. Cheers!